# Base 64 encode image

Tags: php, postman, slim

I want to encode an existing image, this is my current function:

```
public function convertUploadedFileToBase64(UploadedFile $file) {

   return base64_encode(file_get_contents($file->getClientFilename()));

}
```

So I know that $file is a correct variable, I'm using Postman and it shows me with var_dump that $file contains the image, but it looks like the encoding doesnt work.

Before that I use a function which checks if the file is a valid image:

```
public function checkIfUploadedFileIsValid(UploadedFile $file)
{


    $imageInfo = getimagesize($file->file);
    if ($imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/png") ||
        $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/jpeg") ||
        $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/gif") ||
        $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/psd") ||
        $imageInfo['mime'] == ("image/bmp")) {

        return $file;

    }

    throw new \Exception("Image Invalid", 400);


}
```

And this does work, but the base64 encoding seems to be wrong.

Thank you very much!

Comment: _but it looks like the encoding doesnt work_ That is not a good enough description of your issue. Please be more specific

Comment: It would also be useful to see a bit more code AND know what is in `$file->getClientFilename()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well I guess that there is something wrong with the code above. There is a variable called file which contains an image (.png), I want to encode this image.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the little code you've shown, as far as we can tell. We don't know what goes in, we don't know what happens with what comes out, and we don't know what doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `return base64_encode(file_get_contents($file->file));`

Comment: Yes, Lawrence might be right, you're encoding the file name, not the file content.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware $file gets in, which is an image, and I want to convert this file to base64 which doesnt work

Comment: @LawrenceCherone So now this is basically a TYPO I think

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That was the solution, thank you!

Comment: No worries glad to help.. prob close as typo yeah..

Comment: In `checkIfUploadedFileIsValid` you use `$file->file` correctly, but in `convertUploadedFileToBase64` you're using `$file->getClientFilename()` instead, which is the original filename sent by client (not event the filename used to store temporary file on your server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't known what framework you are working on but seems $file->file is path to the uploaded file so you can use

> return base64_encode(file_get_contents($file->file));

Hope it helps